# How to update nested models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have a really simple class, representing an order. This order, will have a status (pending, in progress, sent), which is a class of its own. It is linked via an ID.

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    // ...other properties

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public StatusModel Status { get; set; }
}
```

So when I update the `StatusId`, I (obviously) also want to update status. But what is the best way to do this, in Entity Framework. I can think of two ways, but I am not sure which is more "correct" or why.

- When changing the `StatusId`, also load the matching `StatusModel` and assign this to the job (creates one more read from the database).
- After having saved the order to the database (with the new `StatusId`), reload the entire order (also another read, but potentially a lot more data to read).

While both of the above works, it doesn't really seem to fit the "smartness" of Entity Framework. Isn't there some way to automatically update the `public StatusModel Status` property, when changing the related foreign key (`StatusId`), i.e. something like this:

```
public void ChangeStatus(OrderModel order, int newStatusId) 
{
    // Get the db context
    var ctx = GetMyDbContext();

    // Update the order from the input. Since the order from the input, 
    // will be used afterwards, it is important that it stays in sync 
    // with the database
    order.StatusId = newStatusId;

    // Find the matching order in the database/DbContext and update it
    var orderToUpdate = ctx.Orders.First(o => o.OrderId = order.OrderId)
    ctx.Entry(orderToUpdate ).CurrentValues.SetValues(job);

    // Save the changes made to the database/DbContext
    await ctx.SaveChanges();
    // Do something clever to update the `Status` of the `order`
}
```

Comment: Please make it clear what you are actually wanting? Are you wanting whenever the `StatusId` of an `order` is changed then whole `Status` object of the` order` also should be changed?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes, I am looking for some EF-Core functionality which handles the update of `Status` automatically, when its foreign key (`StatusId`) is updated. I apologize if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Its not possible possible without realoading the whole order with status after the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private int _statusId;

    public int StatusId { get => _statusId; set {
            _statusId = value;
            //call StatusModel update function
        }
    }
```

Encapsulation may help you.

Comment: While that would definitely ensure an update, it would mean that I have to put the database methods inside the `OrderModel` (right now I have all DB methods in a separate class). Are you sure this is the way to do it? I have never seen anyone do it like that.

Comment: I prefer do it with database trigger or procedure but i wrote that answer because you would like to use entity framework for that action.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to statuses , i create an enum that represtnts the status and make a property in the model with that enum  like the following :

```
 public enum Status :int
    {
        Pending,
        Inprogress,
        Sent

    }

    public class OrderModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        // ...other properties
        public Status OrderStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

this will be better in terms of performance (since there will be no joins ) .
Additionally , then we could write some code to create tables with all DbEnums (if you need to represent this on database) .

Comment: In the simple case, I see your point. But what if `Status` has other relations, for instance to something called "NextProcessStep"?